# Simple way to extract data from XML with Java

Tags: java, regex, xml

What would be the simplest way to extract data from XML in Java?
The XML data is always in the form:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<groups>GROUPNAME</groups>
```

and all I want to do is capture the groupname in a string.
I've tried using a regular expression, but I'm struggleing to write the pattern code:

```
String xmlline = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<groups>XWiki.G_SW_DEV</groups>";
String pattern = "";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(xmlline);
if(m.find()){
    ....                     
}
```

As described in:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Any advice on the pattern code or is there a better way to extract the XML data?

Comment: Use libraries like XPath or similar, not regular expressions. You wouldnt drive a screw with a hammer if you have a screwdriver already at home ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Classical advice: dont use regex. It seems easy at begining, but it's not so easy.

and there are many classical libraries for XML which do it well !

see this:
[Java:XML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232377/javaxml-parser)

and then, you only need to do this to retrieve elements:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("groups")
```

[getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947248/getelementsbytagname)

and, something like that

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("method").item(0).getTextContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB marshalling

Example: If you want to read a customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="100">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>Martin</name>
</customer>
```

Step 1: Map the xml to class file

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

String name;
int age;
int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

@XmlElement
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

```
Step 2: Write a reader class


import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class ReadXml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File file = new File("D:\\customer.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println("Name :" + customer.getName());
        System.out.println("Age :" + customer.getAge());
        System.out.println("Id :" + customer.getId());

}

}


output:

Name :Martin
Age :29
Id :100
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Java ecosystem exist three different xml-parser approaches. Two of them are stream-based, working with events. The third uses a tree-model (DOM --> Document Object Model) of the document.
The stream models are suitable for large documents, whereas the DOM parser are usually considered easier/nicer to program.

---

Stream/Event:

- SAX (Simple API for XML) --> you can implement a DocumentHandler that can react to certain events. "Push"-Parser, as it "pushes" events to your Handler.
- StAX (Stream API for XML) --> "Pull"-Parser, you have to fetch the next event from the parser and can react to it.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895124/what-is-push-approach-and-pull-approach-to-parsing)

DOM:

Take a look at the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html)