# Get Data from file between start and end words

Tags: java, text

I have the dataset of reviews of products and I want to extract text between  text  from that file and print.How can I extract Data 
File contains data in the following format

```
<review> id 
<reviewer></reviewer> 
<start word></end word> 
</review>
```

my code is like

```
File file = new File("D://Data/Dataset/unlabeled.review");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(bytes);
    fis.close();
    String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(text.substring(text.indexOf("<start word>"), text.lastIndexOf("</end word>")));
```

Comment: With some code.. What did you try?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129040/simple-way-to-extract-data-from-xml-with-java for example

Answer (score 1):

Your extraction code is this:

```
    text.substring(text.indexOf("<review_text>"), 
                   text.lastIndexOf("</review_text>"));
```

There are three problems with this code:

1. The `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` methods return the offset of the first character of some occurrence of the argument string.  But you need to extract from the first character *after* "".
2. If there are multiple `"<review_text>"` / `"</review_text>"` pairs, then your code doesn't extract the the text between each pair.
3. If there is no `"<review_text>"` or no `"</review_text>"`, then one or both of the index-of calls will return -1, and that will lead to an exception in the `substring` call.